# How to upload file to server using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I'd like to know a simple technique through which i can upload media files into my server using angularjs. 
I know there are a bunch of APIs available, but i'd like to know how its done than actually doing it just like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `formData` html5 api, but make sure your browser supports formData.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata/

[How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)